# Java Swing insert to database across multiple threads

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, concurrency

I have a scenario where the swing application will be receiving multiple online orders, It can be N number of requests at the same time, As the orders need to be persisted to multiple tables there is a need to use transaction.

How to write all the orders to the database (mySQL) concurrently?

Comment: How do you identify a order and all it's elements? Do you know how to create a transaction in JDBC and commit that transaction?  I can't see multiple thread been an issue, so long as you can determine the constraints of the order/transaction

Comment: Identifying orders is not an issue. Yes I do know how to create and commit transaction. Sharing the same connection to multiple threads and doing transaction won't be a problem?. Or do we need to create connection for each thread separately? Or using a queue will be better?

Comment: Ahh, the true question - okay, yes, you should probably consider using some kind of connection pool. Depending on your needs, you might consider using some kind of blocking queue, so when connections are exhausted, new requests (for connections) will wait, but that’s up to you

Comment: That might not have been as clear as it should have been, no,’I don’t recommend sharing a connection across threads - but, I don’t have the experience to say if this is good or bad, I’d just err on the side of caution

Comment: Don't share a connection on multiple threads concurrently. Use a connection pool, acquire a connection for a unit of work and close it as soon as possible (which returns it to the pool).

Comment: Thanks for the update! currently using pooled connection.